# The duplicated name appears after reopen

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid with textbox in it for user to input some entries. The validation method is the `Onsourceupdated` event to validate duplicated entries. It validates and sets the textbox to empty and sends a message to user that the same name exists.

However, after the window is closed and reopen, the duplicated names appears in the textbox again.

This is MVVM and the current file(RegionQueryView.xaml.cs)doesn't have the access to the name property. How do I keep the textbox empty when it is reopen?

```
private void RigionNameOnSourceupdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;


    if (textBox != null)
    {
        string name = textBox.Text;

        StringBuilder errorMessage = null;

        RegionQueryViewModel queryViewModel = DataContext as RegionQueryViewModel;
        //RegionQueryViewModel selectedItem = (RegionQueryViewModel) _regionQueryListBox.SelectedItem;
        if (queryViewModel != null)
        {

            if (queryViewModel.Model.Any(q => q.RegionName == textBox.Text))
            {
                errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
                errorMessage.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} already exists in the list.", textBox.Text));

            }

            if (errorMessage != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage.ToString(), "Item Already Exists");
                textBox.Text = "";


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the view model? Have you tried making it transient?

Comment: The instance of the view model is here: RegionQueryViewModel queryViewModel = DataContext as RegionQueryViewModel. But the name property is not in the view model. It is in RegionQuery.